# limit filesize if uploaded images with laravel

Tags: image, laravel, upload, image-resizing

The client asked me to limit the photos size uploaded by users to 1MB max .. I am using laravel 5.4
first, when I use  $image->save() the size is automatically decreased and I don't know the reason
second, is there a way to target the file size not the image dimensions size?

Answer (score 0):

For limiting the size of an input file, you can use the size validation :

### size:value

The field under validation must have a size matching the given value. For string data, value corresponds to the number of characters. For numeric data, value corresponds to a given integer value. For an array, size corresponds to the `count` of the array. For files, size corresponds to the file size in kilobytes.

What is the difference between the 2 sizes ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->validate($request, [
  'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
]);
```

check this link

http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-53-image-dimension-validation-rules-exampleexample.html

Comment: I want to automatically downgrade the size of the photo if it is larger than 1Mb